# Create X509 certificate with "Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey" and "Curve: x25519"

Tags: openssl, x509certificate

My team is working on software to sign X509 certificates to meet an industry-specific standard. The standard requires that we must use an end-device certificate with "Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey", and also "Curve: X25519 (1.3.101.110)". There's an example certificate in the spec that contains this snippet:

```
Subject Public Key Info:
    Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
    Public-Key: (256 bit)
    pub:
        [key]
    Curve: X25519 (1.3.101.110)
```

There's no indication in the standard that `id-ecPublicKey` maps to OID 1.2.840.10045.2.1, but I can't see how it could be anything else.

I've been having a hell of a time getting OpenSSL to produce this exact output. We ran across [this gist](https://gist.github.com/zhangxd926/36305022305123338c6b3444dabb7476) about using OpenSSL to generate something using OID 1.2.840.10045.2.1, but I can't figure out how to combine that with `X25519 (1.3.101.110)`.

If we use `openssl genpkey` to create an `EC` key like that gist indicates, we can produce a certificate like this:

```
# Generate EC key id
openssl genpkey -algorithm EC -pkeyopt ec_paramgen_curve:P-256 -pkeyopt ec_param_enc:named_curve -out device.priv.pem

# Create cert request
openssl req -new -key device.priv.pem -out device.csr.pem

pushd ../signer

# Sign the request
openssl ca -config openssl.cnf -key signer.key.pem -days 365 -notext -md sha256 \
        -batch -in ../device/device.csr.pem -out ../device/device.cert.pem
```

And it yields a certificate containing the following text and DER data - great; it uses `id-ecPublicKey`, and the expected `OID`

```
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
                Public-Key: (256 bit)
                pub:
                    [key]
                ASN1 OID: prime256v1
                NIST CURVE: P-256

------

370  89:     SEQUENCE {
372  19:       SEQUENCE {
374   7:         OBJECT IDENTIFIER ecPublicKey (1 2 840 10045 2 1)
383   8:         OBJECT IDENTIFIER prime256v1 (1 2 840 10045 3 1 7)
       :         }
393  66:       BIT STRING
       :         ...
       :       }
       :     }
```

However, we can't just swap out `-algorithm EC` for `-algorithm X25519` because that won't allow us to sign the request. We *can* use `-force_pubkey` when signing the request to swap in a different public key, like this:

```
# Generate the device's public/private key pair
openssl genpkey -algorithm x25519 -out device.priv.pem
openssl pkey -in device.priv.pem -pubout -out device.pub.pem

# Use a separate ed25519 key to create a certificate reuqest
openssl genpkey -algorithm ed25519 -out device.req.priv.pem
openssl req -new -key device.req.priv.pem -out device.csr.pem

pushd ../signer

# Substitute in the x25519 public key when signing
openssl x509 -req -CAkey signer.priv.pem -CA signer.cert.pem -CAcreateserial \
    -force_pubkey ../device/device.pub.pem -keyform PEM \
    -in ../device/device.csr.pem -out ../device/device.cert.pem
```

This approach yields a cert with public key OID `1.3.101.110`, but it's algorithm type X25519, not `id-ecPublicKey`

```
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: X25519
                X25519 Public-Key:
                pub:
                    [key]

-------

388  42:     SEQUENCE {
390   5:       SEQUENCE {
392   3:         OBJECT IDENTIFIER curveX25519 (1 3 101 110)
       :         }
397  33:       BIT STRING
       :         ...
       :       }
       :     }
```

So my question boils down to "can we use the OpenSSL command line tools to do what I'm trying to do, or is it necessary to write a tool using `libcrypto` to directly manipulate the ASN1 data into the form we need?"

Comment: Your 'industry' is wrong. `id-ecPublicKey` is only valid for X9-defined algorithms using Weierstrass-form curves, not those from Bernstein et al. The correct spec for PKIX (though maybe not all X.509) is RFC 8410, which defines these as separate algorithm values with parameters absent, and that's what OpenSSL implements, as you saw. For something else, yes you must write it yourself, and you should not expect standard tools to understand or accept it.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Could you maybe describe for my own personal edification where I should have started looking to reach this conclusion? Encryption RFCs are pretty new to me and I don't have any experience for searching through them to find something like this.

I think the spec we're working against is still in a semi-draft state, so hopefully we can push that to change.

Comment: In this case it's easy because X25519 (and Ed25519, and the 448's) are in the title; e.g. goto www.rfc-editor.org and put X25519 in the search box, and mmediately see one of the few results is PKIX. But overall the PKIX RFCs are pretty fragmented, not consistently linked, and not in an IANA registry like many (most?) other useful Internet things. Personally I keep a cheat sheet of the ones I've found, but that doesn't help you :-| Best of luck pushing.